# How to hide "Maven Dependencies" in Package Explorer

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

Is there a way to hide the `Maven Dependencies` classpath container in the Package Explorer? Everytime I jump into a class of a dependency, the Maven Dependencies tree is expanded to the class (if "Link with Editor" is selected, which is my preferred setting). Navigating to own classes or resources then requires lots of scrolling in the Package Explorer, which is quite annoying.

Is there a way to hide the "Maven Dependencies" classpath container or avoid that its get expanded automatically without having to deactivate "Link with Editor"?

[image]

Comment: If possible add the screenshot

Comment: I'm not sure but you might be able to achieve this with a working set. A little laborious maybe but could work.

Comment: If you're using "link with editor" then the package explorer should jump back to your own class when you go back to it by pressing the back button.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a small triangle in the *Package Explorer's* upper right corner. You can create *Filters* to hide stuff (either by name, or maybe there is a hide Maven modules built-in filter by default depending on which plugin you use). I think that could help you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can indeed enter "Maven Dependency" in the "Name filter patterns" on top of the Filters page and the enries are hidden: http://i.imgur.com/jQzXiIK.png

Comment: @James Glad to hear it helps! I've added your screenshot to the answer, hope you don't mind it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse also has a predefined filter "Hide libraries from external" that will solve your issue. At least in Luna